# How to perform action on clicking a QMenu object only?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qmenu, qaction

Here's a snapshot of the GUI. I want to perform simple actions solely by clicking on `QMenu` object Help. This `QMenu` object does NOT have any submenus.[image: Perform action when Help menu is clicked]

Can you please advise me how to perform actions when only the `QMenu` is clicked
Here's what I have tried, but I got an empty output.

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSignalMapper>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    void createActions();
    QSignalMapper *pSignalMapper;

private slots:
    void help();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    createActions();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    pSignalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    connect(ui->menuHelp, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(help()));

}

void MainWindow::help()
{
    qDebug()<<"inside help qdialog";
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <ui_mainwindow.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output when I click on Help `QMenu`, absolutely nothing:

```
Starting E:\Qt2\modules\guiPrototype2\build-guiPrototype2-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\debug\guiPrototype2.exe...
```

Comment: My friend, you can add `QAction` directly to the `QMenuBar`, your `menuHelp` should be a `QAction` not a `QMenu`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would try to do the following:

```
void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    [..]
    connect(ui->menuHelp, SIGNAL(aboutToShow()), this, SLOT(help()));
}

void MainWindow::help()
{
    qDebug()<<"inside help qdialog";
}
```

Comment: with that there is a bug here, when moving mouse on this menu, without clicking, the slot trigering automatically.

Answer (score 8):

The reason it doesn't work, is because you are not triggering any action.

[*This signal is emitted when an action in a menu belonging to this menubar is triggered as a result of a mouse click; action is the action that caused the signal to be emitted.*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmenu.html#triggered)

What you should do is add an action to your `QMenuBar` instead of a `QMenu`.

```
QAction *helpAction = ui->menuBar->addAction("Help");
connect(helpAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(help()));
```

Comment: triggered() SIGNAL doesn't work in this specific case.

Comment: @SaiKamat Because you are using `QMenu`. Read my answer. It works as I have tested it.

Comment: thank u, thuga. i agree with u, triggered() works when we have QAction. In this case I apologize I for not mentioning that there are no QAction items. I was looking for a method to work with QMenu only, as mentioned. :)

Comment: @SaiKamat I know. I was trying to point out that you should use `QAction` instead of `QMenu`. Using `QMenu` object like a `QAction` object is an ugly hacky way of doing things. `QMenu` is a menu widget, and that's what it should do. Provide a menu.

Comment: This is neater than the accepted answer. With the QMenu::aboutToShow() signal, the menu bar remains selected after I clicked the menu control, which spoils the user experience a bit. This method works more smoothly.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely works! After creating a new `QMenuBar` object, one can use `QMainWindow::setMenuBar` to set it as the menu bar of the window.