# Qt Connect trigger SIGNAL for QMenu

Tags: qt, qt5, qobject, qmenu, qaction

I have a "Recent files" file menu as QMenu, like: File-->Recent files.
In that I create dynamically several QActions with the recently opened files listed. That works.

But I want to trigger a seperate SLOT when I click on that Recent files QMenu.

```
connect(ui->menuRecently_Open, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(onRecentOpenFiles(QAction*)));
```

and a TRIGGER debug message should printed out

```
void MainWindow::onRecentOpenFiles(QAction* action)
{
  qDebug() << "TRIGGER";
}
```

But nothing happens ?

Comment: May be the reason is: [This signal is emitted for the main parent menu in a hierarchy. Hence, only the parent menu needs to be connected to a slot; sub-menus need not be connected.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qmenu.html#triggered).

Comment: @Amartel so its parent is the "File" which is also a QMenu. But how could I solve that then?

Comment: Well, you could connect to `ui->menuFile`.

Comment: @Amartel That does not change anything. I can not trigger that slot, just by clicking on a QMenu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform action on clicking a QMenu object only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197496/how-to-perform-action-on-clicking-a-qmenu-object-only)

Answer (score 3):

This works as expected:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    QMenu *fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("File"));
    QMenu *recentMenu = fileMenu->addMenu(tr("Recent"));
    recentMenu->addAction(tr("File1"));
    recentMenu->addAction(tr("File2"));
    recentMenu->addAction(tr("File3"));

    connect(recentMenu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*))
            , SLOT(onRecentOpenFiles(QAction*)));
}

void MainWindow::onRecentOpenFiles(QAction *action)
{
    qDebug() << action;
}
```

And you are doing something wrong, or not telling us everything.

Comment: I have it exactly the same way as you have in your example, except for one thing: I added the fileMenu in the Qt Creator design mode.

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem, and I found I didn't add slot funciton under "private slots:" but to "private".

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with more details and clarification. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).